# Grails 3 - Security without plugins

Tags: spring, grails, spring-security

I am implementing Spring Security with SAML on a Grails 3.x application without the use of plugins.

I have added the necessary jars as below :

```
     compile group: 'ca.juliusdavies', name: 'not-yet-commons-ssl', version: '0.3.17'
     compile 'org.opensaml:opensaml:2.6.0'
     compile 'org.opensaml:openws:1.4.1'
     compile 'org.opensaml:xmltooling:1.3.1'
     compile group: 'org.springframework.security', name: 'spring-security-core', version: '3.2.5.RELEASE'
     compile group: 'org.springframework.security', name: 'spring-security-config', version: '3.2.5.RELEASE'
     compile group: 'org.springframework.security.extensions', name: 'spring-security-saml2-core', version: '1.0.5.BUILD-SNAPSHOT'
```

I have my securitycontext.xml file integrated within resources.groovy.

```
beans = {
        importBeans('classpath:security/springSecuritySamlBeans.xml')
}
```

I need to add the following security filters in my web.xml but in Grails 3 this is not possible.Can anyone suggest where these need to be added and how they can be added.

```
<filter>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>
```

From what i read these filters need to be defined in resources.groovy but I am not sure how this is done.

Comment: Please refer https://docs.grails.org/latest/guide/spring.html#_using_beanbuilder_with_spring_mvc

Answer (score 2):

> I need to add the following security filters in my web.xml but in
>   Grails 3 this is not possible.

You probably don't really need to add them in `web.xml`.  You probably just need them to be applied in your app.  A way to do that in Grails 3 is with a `FilterRegistrationBean`.  See https://github.com/grails/grails-core/blob/6b30c22ac9a3758bde53844f807ea781ca7e3c9d/grails-plugin-controllers/src/main/groovy/org/grails/plugins/web/controllers/ControllersGrailsPlugin.groovy#L93-L112 for several examples.  You may want to do something similar in your app's `resources.groovy`.

Answer (score 0):

Looks to me it still sounds like a hassle. Instead of making this work and you have no clarity on what's going on, you might as well delegate your user registration workflow to a third party service eg Firebase.

Use an interceptor to write that.

Comment: "Looks to me it still sounds like a hassle." - I don't understand that comment.  The question was related to not knowing how to register a servlet filter in Grails 3, the solution is to add a statement to `resources.groovy`.  That doesn't seem like a hassle and is the documented best practice for how to register a servlet filter in Grails 3.

Comment: The answer given here would be more appropriate if the question was about what is the best practice for managing registration workflow.  It still wouldn't be an answer I would agree with, but it would at least be a valid answer to the question.  As is, this does not answer the question asked.